# In solr7.5, How to sort by facet.pivot's the second level field's count?

Tags: sorting, solr, pivot

**solr query : http://192.168.106.58:8983/solr/search/select?q=*:*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.pivot=location.comm,search.resourcetype**

I use facet.pivot to query, but I want to sort with count of (search.resourcetype=somevalue)， for example :
[image]

Comment: please help me! Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean you want to sort with count equals to somevalue? It doesn’t look to me like sorting

Comment: @Mysterion, I want to sort with count of (search.resourcetype=somevalue). Now, could you understand me ?

Comment: @Mysterion, please help me! Thank you very much!